# Import MS-SQL data into an Access Table ADO

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vb6, inner-join, ado

I hope that you can help me or point me in the right direction. For many years, I have used a very clean and simple method of importing data (within VB6, yes!) from a MS-SQL table into an MS-Access database/table as follows:-

**WORKING QUERY WITH NO INNER JOINS**

```
Dim myConnection As ADODB.connection
Dim mySQL As String
Set myConnection = New ADODB.connection
myConnection.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & "Dbq=DB1.mdb;" & "DefaultDir=C:\Temp;" & "Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
mySQL = "SELECT * INTO [Xray] FROM [ODBC;Driver=SQL Server; SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=myDatabase;UID=myUID;PWD=myPassword;].[ShipTo] WHERE [ShipTo].Company='ABC001'"
myConnection.Execute mySQL
Set myConnection = Nothing
```

However, for the first time, I now need to start working with Inner Joins. I thought that I could do something as simple as above, but I have come unstuck rather heavily and have no idea how to progress. My Inner Join query is below:-

```
SELECT        
    dbo.InvcHead.InvoiceNum AS DocNum, 
    SUM(dbo.InvcTax.TaxAmt) AS DocTaxAmt
FROM                        
    dbo.InvcTax
        INNER JOIN
    dbo.InvcHead ON (dbo.InvcTax.InvoiceNum = dbo.InvcHead.InvoiceNum) 
GROUP BY 
dbo.InvcHead.InvoiceNum**
```

Because of my clear lack of experience using joins with my tried and tested method, I get an error which is probably because of my syntax, but I just cannot see the light. Below is the new connection string/query attempt:-

**FAILED QUERY WITH INNER JOINS**

```
Dim myConnection As ADODB.connection
Dim mySQL As String

Set myConnection = New ADODB.connection
myConnection.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};" & "Dbq= DB1.mdb;" & "DefaultDir= C:\Temp;" & "Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"

mySQL = ""
mySQL = mySQL & "SELECT "
mySQL = mySQL & "dbo.InvcHead.InvoiceNum AS DocNum, "
mySQL = mySQL & "SUM(dbo.InvcTax.TaxAmt) As Doctaxamt "
mySQL = mySQL & "INTO [Xray] FROM [ODBC;Driver=SQL Server; SERVER= myServer;DATABASE= myDatabase;UID= myUID;PWD=myPassword;].[dbo.InvcTax] "
mySQL = mySQL & "Inner Join dbo.InvcHead ON (dbo.InvcTax.InvoiceNum = dbo.InvcHead.InvoiceNum)"
mySQL = mySQL & "Group By dbo.InvcHead.Invoicenum"

myConnection.Execute mySQL
Set myConnection = Nothing
```

The error message I get is **"Syntax Error in Join Operation"**

Is it possible to do this extraction using this method with an inner join query? I suspect my problem relates to the area of the script where I reference the first table of the join.

.[dbo.InvcTax] "

If this is not possible, is there a way to create a table dynamically (as I have done) but from a recordset instead?

Any help of a steer in the right direction will be massively appreciated.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Hello Larnu, thanks so much for the info. That is the first thing I will do and post conversion, test again to see if it helps. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: It's unlikely to fix your error, it's more me pointing out you're using syntax that is on the deprecation list.

Comment: like mentioned already, make your query more readable, for example like this SELECT h.InvoiceNum AS DocNum, SUM(t.TaxAmt) AS DocTaxAmt FROM   dbo.InvcTax t INNER JOIN dbo.InvcHead h ON t.InvoiceNum = h.InvoiceNum GROUP BY h.InvoiceNum It will not fix your error, but help us and others help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dbo prefix fails in Access SQL and you miss the database reference for the second table:

```vb
mySQL = ""
mySQL = mySQL & "SELECT "
mySQL = mySQL & "T1.InvoiceNum AS DocNum, "
mySQL = mySQL & "SUM(T1.TaxAmt) As Doctaxamt "
mySQL = mySQL & "INTO [Xray] FROM [ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=myDatabase;UID=myUID;PWD=myPassword;].dbo.InvcTax AS T1 "
mySQL = mySQL & "INNER JOIN [ODBC;Driver=SQL Server;SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=myDatabase;UID=myUID;PWD=myPassword;].dbo.InvcHead AS T2 ON (T1.InvoiceNum = T2.InvoiceNum)"
mySQL = mySQL & "Group By T2.Invoicenum"
```

Comment: Gustav, thank you so much! Looking at it now, it seems so logical, but of course, I did not have that logic whatsoever. I am getting a field not found error now, but will keep going on this as this is clearly a good sign - thank you so much!

Comment: Quick update, problem with the 'Cannot find the field' error relates to size (number of columns) in InvcHead. Unconfirmed, but scripting InvcTax separately into an Access works fine, but I get the error message when trying to do the InvcHead separately . That means there is nothing wrong with the join, but a problem with the size of the table. If I remove the "insert into" the join works perfectly. No idea now how I will get content out of the recordset into another table. May need to create a smaller version, and then run from the temp:-( Thanks a ton for the knowledge share on the Joins

Comment: Access has a limit of 255 fields for a table/query. If your tables have more fields, you may have to create simple select queries that pull only the fields needed, then use these to build your final query.

Comment: Thanks again Gustav, I did just that and it worked a treat with the join also. Many thanks again. Now need to add an additional join using the knowledge share you provided. Cheers Sir.

Comment: Hello Gustav, I have another question with regards to this. As I am new to Stack Overflow, should this new question be posted as another thread, or can I use this thread and add to it? Thanks in advance,

Comment: You should post a new question - for others to chime in - and, if relevant, include a link to this question.

Comment: Will do and many thanks!